# How To Create Non Removable Css Styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I was wondering if there was a way to create non removable css style so that user can't disable the css style by inspect element, looking forward for a helpful answer!**

Comment: You cannot forcibly control the user's browser in any way.

Comment: What's the point anyway? The user can, will, and definitely have access to css styles. Even if you obfuscate them, e.g. using nonsensical class names, they can still get the computed styles using `element.getComputedStyle()`.

Comment: As the user can basically modify the entire Source code of the page theres no way to prohibit editing of css styles in the element inspector. I don't see a reason for doing it anyways, as it will not affect files on your server and it's not your problem if a user messes around with his own copy of the website, is it?

Comment: If you need to do this, it seems like there may be a design issue bigger than CSS lock-down could fix.  What would this be used for, specifically, that even makes a valid use-case for this technique?

Answer (score 0):

You cant Stop from disabling any css element

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do so. Users will always have full access to your code and full control over developer tools. You cannot control the behvaior of the browser through your application.

This is for security and usability reasons: imagine a website stopping you from closing the tab or from navigating away!